# smoke Rendering out is blurred

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I am not convenient to express my settings，So have attached my file

I want to make the smoke more clear，Like an example of a photo

My file:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9AIC7MxieHpdXN1QTdkbTZPZUU
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are showing us an opengl render from the viewport, did you try rendering it on a black background like the photo?

Answer (score -1):

On the ones with all the mushroom clouds, it looks like you need more [resolution](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#settings) in your smoke domain. This will allow it to use a lot more detail.

(Also, this won't change the look, but to make it calculate faster, you can enable [Smoke Adaptive Domain](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#smoke-adaptive-domain) in the domain settings.)

Comment: Did you look at his file? He already uses 128 subdivs for smoke and 3 levels of high res smoke domain with adaptive domain enabled. The bake already takes like 2 hours on my 40 core dual xeon machine, upping the resolution isnt the problem. The problem is hes showing us an opengl render from the viewport.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't know it would show different cloud patterns.